# Every left ideal of $R[x]$ is cyclic implies $R$ a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, division-ring

I need to prove that if every left ideal of $R[x]$ is cyclic as a left $R[x]$-module then $R$ is a division ring.

I don't really understand. So a left ideal $I$ is cyclic as a left $R[x]$-module, let $f(x) \in R[x]$ we can write $I = R[x]f(x)$. $I$ is a left ideal and we can have $(R[x])^2f(x) \subset R[x]f(x)$. Then everything is already good. Where is the  division ring part?

Comment: Just in case, how do you define a ring?  Do you require it to have the multiplicative identity?  That is, does $R$ have $1$?

Comment: @Batominovski Oh I forgot to say, $R$ indeed has $1$. But it didn't seem to be used anywhere.

Comment: I asked just in case, but maybe it is not a necessary assumption.